# Executing code N times and other code N+1 times

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

The question is about while-loops in which I need some code to be executed N times and some other code N+1 times. NOT about concatening Strings, I just use this as bad-coded yet short example.

Let me explain my question by providing an example.

Say I want to concatenate N+1 Strings, by glueing them with "\n", for example. I will have N+1 lines of text then, but I only need to add N times "\n".

Is there any boilerplate solution for this type of loop in which you have to execute some code N times and other code N+1 times? I'm NOT asking for solution to concatenate Strings! That is just a (bad) example. I'm looking for the general solution.

The problem I have with this is code duplication, so to code my example I'll do this (bad pseudo code, I know I have to use StringBuilder etc.):

```
String[] lines = <some array of dimension N+1>;
String total = lines[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++){
    total += "\n" + lines[i];
}
```

The problem becomes worse if the code that has to be executed N+1 times, becomes larger, of course. Then I would do something like

```
codeA(); // adding the line of text
for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++){
    codeB(); // adding the "\n"
    codeA();
}
```

To remove the duplication, you can do this different by checking inside the loop, too, but then I find this quite stupid as I know beforehand that the check is pre-determined, as it will only be false the first iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++){
    if (i > 0){
        codeB(); // adding the "\n"
    }
    codeA();
}
```

Is there any solution for this, a sort of while-loop that initializes once with codeA() en then keeps looping over codeB() and codeA()?

People must have run into this before, I guess. Just wondering if there are any beautiful solutions for this.

Comment: It's just an example. The concrete use case isn't that important, the question is about while-loops in which I need some code to be executed N times and some other code N+1 times.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I spent some efforts in asking this, providing an example. People immediately start picking on the String example but I clearly state that's it's just an example, and that the question is about optimizing the loop by removing duplication of code.

Comment: I actually think this is a good question, I have had to use this pattern quite often. Personally I think adding an `if` statement to treat the first iteration differently (like in your second example) is the cleanest way. The runtime overhead is minimal, it is clear what is happening, and you don't have code duplication.

Comment: @Timmos i agree sometimes people cannot read and think at the same time, please upvote again

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. I want a solution for the general problem, not the String specific one.

Comment: @Heuster You are right about the if-statement in the loop. If nothing else is cleaner, that seems the best solution.

Comment: +1. This is a very tricky question. I think that it is not so much about executing some code n times and other code n+1. It is more about executing a loop by optionally taking a different route on the first or last iteration

Comment: @c.s. You stated it differently but better than me. It is indeed as you describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my dissapointment, I believe that there is no such construct that satisfies the conditions as you have stated them and I will attempt to explain why (though I can't prove it in a strictly mathematical way).

The requirements of the problem are:

1. We have two parts of code: `codeA()` and `codeB()`
2. The two parts are executed a different number of times, N and N+1
3. We want to avoid adding a condition inside the loop
4. We want to execute each part only as many times as strictly necessary

2) is a direct consequence of 1). If we didn't have two parts of code we would not need a different number of executions. We would have a single loop body.

4) is again a consequence of 1). There is no redundant execution if we have a single loop body. We can control its execution through the loop's condition

So the restrictions are basically 1) and 3).

Now inside the loop we need to answer two questions on each iteration: a) do we execute `codeA()`? and b) do we execute `codeB()`? We simply do not have enough information to decide since we only have a single condition (the condition of the loop) and that condition will be used to decide if **both** of the code parts would be executed or not.

So we need to break 1) and/or 3) Either we add the extra condition inside the loop or we delegate the decision to some other code (thus not having two parts anymore).

Apparently an example of delegation could be (I am using the string concatenation example):

```
String [] lines = ...
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   // delegate to a utility class LineBuilder (perhaps an extension of StringBuilder) to concatenate lines
   // this class would still need to check a condition e.g. for the first line to skip the "\n"
   // since we have delegated the decisions we do not have two code parts inside the loop
   lineBuilder.addLine( lines[i] );
}
```

Now a more interesting case of delegation would be if we could delegate the decision to the *data itself* (this might worth keeping in mind). Example:

```
List<Line> lines = Arrays.asList(
             new FirstLine("Every"),    // note this class is different
             new Line("word"), 
             new Line("on"), 
             new Line("separate"), 
             new Line("line") );

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (Line l : lines) {
    // Again the decision is delegated. Data knows how to print itself
    // Line would return: "\n" + s
    // FirstLine would return: s
    sb.append( l.getPrintVersion() );
}
```

Of course all of the above does not mean that you couldn't implement a class that tries to solve the problem. I believe though this is beyond the scope of your original question not to mention that would be an overkill for simple loops

Comment: Woah, I like your use of interfaces here. While it brings in some extra work, you can indeed loop over ILoopWorker, being the first one a LoopWorkerA and all the rest LoopWorkerBA's. LoopWorkerA would then execute ``codeA();`` and LoopWorkerBA would execute ``codeB(); codeA();``. The while-loop doesn't know about the implementation and can therefore just loop over all of its ``ILoopWorker``s, without any if. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. The idea is to _decorate_ your data in order to add functionality that would allow it to know how to handle itself. So the loop just _visits_ all your data similar to the `Visitor` pattern. Please do not forget to accept the answer if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I was waiting for some additional answers but from what I see, I think that your solution is the best answer for the issue in a generalized way. The only problem left with this approach that I can think of is that you have to fill some ILoopWorker[] array with different implementations, so you will still need to have some extra logic for filling that array. The code duplication is now actually propagated into the ILoopWorker implementations (calling codeA() in both workers), but as these classes exist for the single purpose of making the code much cleaner and readable, I think that it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating Strings like this is a bad idea and a much bigger issue IMHO.

However to answer your question I would do

```
String sep = "";
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
for(String s: lines) {
    sb.append(sep).append(s);
    sep = "\n";
}
String all = sb.toString();
```

Note: there is usually a good way to avoid needing to create this String at all such a processing the lines as you get them. It is hard to say without more context.

Comment: The problem is not about concatenating Strings but the question is about while-loops in which I need some code to be executed N times and some other code N+1 times.

Comment: @Timmos If you want to simplify the code, there is always a way to do it. as this example shows.  Exactly how, depends on the example.

Comment: @PeteBelford It is the simplest solution all the same even if it not what the OP expects.  If you compare your answer, can you say why that is simpler?

Comment: Although you removed the check inside the loop, you're still executing N times the assignment `sep = "\n"`, which is only needed once.

Comment: int i = 1; is far more simple, and like your example @PeterLawrey, does not meet the requirements.

Comment: @Timmos While true, the cost is less than a nano-second and with loop unrolling it can be optimised away.  WHile you can suggest alternatives, the cost of them is likely to be far higher. E.g. a missed branch can be 100 clock cycles.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is fairly common, like when you build sql.  This is the pattern that I follow:

```
String[] lines ...//init somehow;
String total = lines[0];
boolean firstTime = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(firstTime) firstTime = false;
    else sb.append('\n');

    sb.append(lines[i]);
}
```

Note that this is not the same, as the first example and here is why:

```
String[] lines = <some array of dimension N+1>;
String total = lines[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N + 1; i++){
    total += "\n" + lines[i];
}
```

Assuming you have an array of [0] = 'line1' and [1] = 'line2'
Here you end up with line1line2\n, when the desired output is:

line1\nline2.

The example I provided is clear, and does not perform poorly.  In fact a much bigger performance gain is made by utilizing StringBuilder/Buffer.  Having clear code is essential for the pro.

Comment: Your check inside the for-loop is exactly what my start post also gives as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i have most of the time the same problem, on the String example i use the StringBuilder as you said, and just delete the characters added to much:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    sb.append(array[i]).append("\n");
}
sb.delete(sb.length-1, sb.length);  // maybe check if sb contains something
```

In the common case i suppose there is no other way than adding the if you suggested. To make the code more clear i would check at the end of the for loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    sb.append(array[i]);
    if(i < N) {
         sb.append("\n");
    }
}
```

But i totally agree this is sad to have this double logic

Comment: Rather than deleting a character you can set the length to one less